# Meaning of "Allowed to push" and "Allowed to merge" in Gitlab

Tags: git, merge, push, gitlab

What's the meaning of "Allowed to push" and "Allowed to merge" in Gitlab protected branches

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting [Gitlab Documentation here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#using-the-allowed-to-merge-and-allowed-to-push-settings)

> Using the "Allowed to push" and "Allowed to merge" settings, you can control the actions that different roles can perform with the protected branch. For example, you could set "Allowed to push" to "No one", and "Allowed to merge" to "Developers + Masters", to require everyone to submit a merge request for changes going into the protected branch

`Allowed to push` allows the set of people to directly [fast-forward commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) and [non-force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to a particular branch, ideally for protected branches it should be allowed only for Maintainers.

`Allowed to merge` allows the set of people to [merge/pull](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#mergepull-requests-with-gitlab-flow) request into a branch, which for Protected branches like **master**, should ideally be only for Maintainers again.

Comment: If I set "allowed to merge" to Maintainers only, wouldn't it prevent others to create Merge Requests?

Answer (score 19):

**Allowed to push** means just that - the user is allowed to `git push` to the branch.

**Allowed to merge** means that the user is allowed to accept merge requests into that branch.